# Error hosting WCF on WAS

Tags: asp.net, wcf, was, wcf-hosting

I am getting this error while hosting my WCF application on windows service. The service is hosted on a server and i want to access it over internet. So i gave it networkservice permission.

```
Service cannot be started. System.ServiceModel.AddressAccessDeniedException: HTTP could not register URL http://+:8085/lupload/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70353 for details). ---> System.Net.HttpListenerException: Access is denied
   at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SharedHttpTransportManager.OnOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManager.Open(TransportChannelListener channelListener)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportManagerContainer.Open(SelectTransportManagersCallback selectTransportManagerCallback)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(Tim...

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Answer (score 0):

`NetworkService` is actually a limited account, you need to go for `LocalSystem` which is the equivalent of an Administrator account. That'll solve your problem.

Comment: Did you restart after changing the identity? Otherwise that change won't be picked up.

Comment: Mmm, tricky one... Can you run `netsh http show servicestate` and look if there's already another process listening on HTTP:8085?

Comment: there is no process running on this port.